# Entity Linq Performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Linq Query

```
(from L in linksRepo.PSM_Links()
                join U in usersRepo.PSM_Users() on L.UserId equals U.Id
         where L.StationId == stationId && L.JobTypeId == 3
         select new VW_PollClerks
         {
             Id = U.Id,
             Forename = U.Forename,
             Surname = U.Surname,
             StaffEmail = U.StaffEmail,
             TelephoneHome = U.TelephoneHome,
             TelephoneWork = U.TelephoneWork,
             TelephoneMobile = U.TelephoneMobile
         }).ToList();
```

If I run this using the entity context directly it completes almost instantly. However when I use repositories for each table as above it takes over 30 seconds to complete. I have broken it down and it appears to be the PSM_Users table that causes the speed issue, why is this? The repository looks like the following

```
public interface IUsersRepository : IDisposable
    {
    IEnumerable<PSM_Users> PSM_Users();
    PSM_Users GetUser(int Id);
    void SaveChanges();
}

public class EFUsersRepostiory : IUsersRepository, IDisposable
{
    private PSMContext db;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public EFUsersRepostiory(PSMContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<PSM_Users> PSM_Users()
    {
        return db.PSM_Users.ToList();
    }

    public PSM_Users GetUser(int Id)
    {
        return db.PSM_Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
```

Below looks identical to me but completes almost instantly.

```
        using (Models.PSMContext db = new PSMContext())
        {
              List<PSM_Users> user = (from L in db.PSM_Links()
                join U in db.GetUser() on L.UserId equals U.Id
         where L.StationId == stationId && L.JobTypeId == 3
         select new VW_PollClerks
         {
             Id = U.Id,
             Forename = U.Forename,
             Surname = U.Surname,
             StaffEmail = U.StaffEmail,
             TelephoneHome = U.TelephoneHome,
             TelephoneWork = U.TelephoneWork,
             TelephoneMobile = U.TelephoneMobile
         }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: The issue has nothing in common with LINQ to Entities, but to your repository design, in particular returning `IEnumerable<T>` which causes loading the whole tables in memory and performing a LINQ to Objects query.

Comment: `db.GetUser()` requires an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the `.ToList();` calls. This will breakdown the build of a query. It will retreive the data to the client and the criteria/where is done clientside. You rather want it to select the rows serverside. Instead of returning a `IEnumerable<>` use the `IQueryable<>` as return type. *(or the type of the `db.PSM_Users`)*

```
public IQueryable<PSM_Users> PSM_Users()
{
    return db.PSM_Users;
}
```

Never use the `ToList()` when it is not needed.